# Finding the closest value in a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find for each price column the next cheapest product available on the day. my data looks something like this

```
data = [['29/10/18', 400, 300, 200], 
        ['29/10/18', 250, 400, 100], 
        ['29/10/18', 600, 600, 300],
        ['30/10/18', 300, 500, 100]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'price 1', 'price2', 'price3'])
```

my output would look something like this

```
date     price1 nearestPrice1 price2 nearestPrice2 
29/10/18 400    250           300    400 
29/10/18 250    400           400    300
29/10/18 600    400           600    400
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain the problem a bit more and also show us what you have tried to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = lambda row, col: df.loc[df[df['date'] == row['date']][col].sub(row[col])\
                    .abs().nsmallest(2).idxmax(), col]

df['nearest_price1'] = df.apply(f, col = 'price 1', axis = 1)
df['nearest_price2'] = df.apply(f, col = 'price2', axis = 1)
df['nearest_price3'] = df.apply(f, col = 'price3', axis = 1)
```

Outputs:

```
       date  price 1  price2  price3  nearest_price1  nearest_price2  \
0  29/10/18      400     300     200             250             400   
1  29/10/18      250     400     100             400             300   
2  29/10/18      600     600     300             400             400   
3  30/10/18      300     500     100             300             500   

   nearest_price3  
0             100  
1             200  
2             200  
3             100
```

Explanation:

Uses a lambda function f, apply this function to each column (`price 1`, `price2`, `price3`), and gets the results.
It works as following:

> 1. By [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) the `price` of other prices in same `date`.
> 2. It looks for the two smallest [`abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) prices using [`nsmallest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html).
> 3. Lastly, use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to index the second smallest price (because the 1st smallest price would be itself having an absolute difference of 0)

Comment: i need to do this on quite a few columns which is taking quite some time to run. do you have any other suggestions to make it more efficient? my dataset has about 160k entries in it

Comment: You can try to do this in NumPy. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490147/increasing-performance-of-nearest-neighbors-of-rows-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you need to find the cheapest prices for a given day starting with the cheapest then the nearest cheapest and so on...

This means that you'd need to first extract all the prices for the given day. You could do this with a simple for loop where for example if the text in the first column is '29/10/18' then add the data from the rest of the columns to a list or make a new DataFrame from it. In either case, once you have all the prices for the data you can use the .sort_values function provided with pandas and specify that you want it as ascending. [Function documentation](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=.sort_values&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: it's not the cheapest price for that day, each row represents a product. I was trying to find the product that was closest price to that one on that day. I hope that makes sense. zwjjoy answer below is what I am looking for but thank you for taking the time to reply